# How to concat two tables into one row with validations (Lumen, Laravel)

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, api, lumen

I'm using Laravel and I'm trying to return this on API:

```
{
id: 1
name: BOM DIA
},
id: 2
name: BOM DIA (SUPERM VANEZA, BATISTA & IZEPE, BOM DIA)
}
```

But I'm confused. I have a table named '**Teams**', and at this table, some columns have a number '**biid**'. This '**biid**' is the same information from another table name '**Clients**'.

More than one '**Clients**' can have same '**biid**', but '**Teams**' only have unique '**biid**' or don't have any '**biid**'.

I wanna to concat '**Teams**' who has '**biid**' with column named '**slug**' in table '**Clients**'.

Tables:
[image: Client table]
[image: Team table]

This should be like this:

[image: Example]

How can I even think in make this?

Comment: Can you share with us the migrations from your laravel application ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you need relations to do it if i know your problem

so let's talk about relation in your case `Teams` as **many** `clients`

> the relation in your model teams will be this:

```php
public function client(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Client::class);
}
```

> What laravel does with `belongsToMany` method ?
>
> > for each client who as the same id's who you references teams and laravel will add it to you Eloquent Object.

> Your client has one teams
> soin your client model if you named it client :

```php
public function team(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Model::class);
}
```

to get the detail of relation who you need :

> you will need to make the relations request, this will contribute to remove `n +1` problem:

```php
$clients = Client::with(['team']); 
$teams = Team::with(['client']);
// here i don't know if you need ->get() try without and with
```

> To access the relations:

```php
foreach($clients as $client){
    echo $client->team->name;
}

foreach($teams->client as $team){
    echo $team->name;
}

// or 

foreach($teams as $team){
    echo $team->client->name;
}
```

> But i think for that you need to rename you column because that are not explicit for laravel
>
> > to access relations you column need to have `client_id` and `team_id` to work.